# weak derivative and the value of a integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $0 < r < R$ and $p>1$ and consider the function

$$u(x) = \displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle\int_{|x|}^{R} t^{-1 }dt}{\displaystyle\int_{r}^{R} t^{-1 }dt},$$
if $r < |x|< R$ , and $u=1$ if $0\leq |x| \leq r$

Show that $\displaystyle\int_{B(0,R)} |\nabla u |^{p} \ dx =  \int_{B(0,1)} 1 \ dx \ \ ({ln(R/r)})^p$

the gradient is in the weak sense.

I think the gradient is given in the natural way ( imagining u as a derivable function)

My ideas:
the gradient (thinking as I said before) is :

$$ \nabla u (x) = \frac{1}{ln (\frac{R}{r})}( \frac{x_1}{|x|^2},...,\frac{x_n}{|x|^2})$$
if $r < |x|< R$ and zero in the other case.

Then

$$ \displaystyle\int_{B(0,R)} |\nabla u|^p \ dx \leq \displaystyle\int_{B(0,R) - B(0,r)} \frac{1}{(|x|ln(R/r))^p} = \frac{1}{(ln(R/r))^p} \displaystyle\int_{B(0,R) - B(0,r)} \frac{1}{|x|^p} \ dx$$

I stopped here =\    ....

Soemone can give me a help?

thanks in advance

Comment: You could start by working out an explicit formula for $u(x)$.